# Chain rule or power rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Attempting a multivariable question.

$$f(x,z) = 6z^3 - 5(x-z)^2 - 4x$$

I want to do the various first and second derivatives of this ($dy/dx$,$dy/dx$, $d^2y/dxdz$) but I'm stuck on the first derivative. My issue is with the middle term "$5(x-z)^2$". Do i use chain rule and make it "$10(x-z)^2$" or do i use power rule and it just becomes $10(x-z)$?

Comment: If it helps you reason between them, recall that $(x-z)^2$ can be expanded as $x^2-2xz+z^2$.  This should be clear how to approach now.

Comment: How did you apply the chain rule?